# Ionic: Why if I have the title attribute nothing shows up on the app (?)

Tags: ios, ionic-framework

I am using `ion-tabs` and the last version of Ionic framework, as you can see [here](http://codepen.io/gnomeontherun/pen/tbvdH) at the bottom there are 3 options: Home, About, Contact.

I want to display something similar in my app, the icons are displaying correctly but with no title.

[this is what I am getting](http://storage2.static.itmages.com/i/15/0126/h_1422303144_6471387_e53ade1ed5.png) instead of [this](http://storage4.static.itmages.com/i/15/0126/h_1422303255_7262562_49631dd25e.png)

and here my code:

```
 <ion-tabs class="tabs-positive tabs-icon-only">

  <ion-tab title="Straight" icon-on="ion-android-arrow-forward" icon-off="ion-ios-arrow-thin-right" ng-click="showBetType('displayStraight')">
    Straight
  </ion-tab>
  <ion-tab title="Parlay & Robin" icon-on="ion-ios-loop-strong" icon-off="ion-ios-loop" ng-click="showBetType('displayParlayRobin')">
    Parlay & Robin
  </ion-tab>
  <ion-tab icon-on="ion-ios-redo" icon-off="ion-ios-redo-outline" ng-click="showBetType('displayParlayIfBet')">
    If & Reverse
  </ion-tab>
  <ion-tab icon-on="ion-arrow-shrink" icon-off="ion-arrow-expand" ng-click="showBetType('displayParlayTeaser')">
    Teaser
  </ion-tab>

</ion-tabs>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to remove the **tabs-icon-only** class form ion-tabs.

```
<ion-tabs class="tabs-positive"> 

 ...
```